# Is it possible to enable click and drag in Google Maps Flutter when scrollGestureEnabled is set to false?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, web

I have a flutter web app that uses Google maps. I have set the scrollGestureEnabled to false in order to prevent the map from zooming as the user scrolls down the page. However, I need the user to be able to click and drag the map to view different areas. But the dragging feature is disabled as soon as the scroll gesture is set to false. Is it possible to enable click and drag when scrollGestureEnabled is false? If so, are there any popular workarounds?

I have changed the scrollGestureEnabled to true and the click and drag feature works correctly, but the user experience is frustrating because the map takes up a large portion of the UI and as the user scrolls down the page, the map zooms, making it less useful.

Comment: What I can think of is try to create a button or some kind of condition that will toggle the `scrollGestureEnabled`. With that, the user will have the freedom to either control the map, or just scroll through the map when navigating the app page. Can you try that out?